# How to use maven without setting M2_HOME system variable?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have **maven 3** setup on my D: drive.   Due to lack of administrative access I dont want to set **M2_HOME** variable.

Is there any other workaround for that? or not possible?

Comment: I guess you could `cd` to installation directory and launch maven from there as well. Just make sure that you have `JAVA_HOME` env variable set.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov - but for many maven operations we need to inside project wherever pom.xml is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need enviromental variable to use maven. It's just handy in command line, so you can just type

```
mvn clean install
```

instead of

```
D:\maven3\...\mvn.bin clean install
```

or something like that.

In most IDEs you can manually set it in classpath, for example in Eclipse.